# Impedir la captura de un caracter (espacio) en un textbox (.net Windows.Forms)

Tags: c#, windows-forms

En una aplicación  de escritorio escrita en C# con Windows Form necesito programar en el evento KeyPress de un textbox un comportamiento que no permita la captura de espacios.

El siguiente es el código con el que lo he intentado

```
private void txtBuscarDocumento_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) // Funciona bien
   {
      e.Handled = false;
   }
   else if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) // Funciona bien
   {
      e.Handled = false;
   }
   else if (Char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar)) // Funciona bien
   {
      e.Handled = false;
   }
   else if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar)) // No me funciona con espacios en blanco
   {
       e.Handled = false;
   }
   else
   {
       e.Handled = true;
   }

   //No permite copiar contenido en el textbox
   Clipboard.Clear();
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ya miraste aca? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace?view=net-6.0 .. y de paso.. Clipboard.Clear();
si tu programa me borra el clipboard, yo personalmente te mato... y si tenia guardada una imagen o un link que nada que ver con tu programa?

Answer (score 1):

Gente logre evitar que no ingresen espacios en blanco. Anule la tecla tab y la espaciadora. Muchas gracias por sus comentarios y sugerencias.

```
private void frmListadoPacientes_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   //Al presionar la tecla enter cambia el foco al campo
   if (e.KeyChar == (char)(Keys.Enter))
   {
      e.Handled = true;
      SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
   }

   if (Char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar))
   {
      e.Handled = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para no permitir espacios en blanco puedes hacer dentro del **evento KeyPress**:

```
if (char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))
{
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

Aquí preguntas si el caracter introducido es un espacio en blanco (no necesariamente la barra espaciadora, hay muchos caracteres en blanco como el Tabulador) y en caso de ser un espacio en blanco, se invalida esa pulsación haciendo que el **handled** sea **True**.

o también puedes hacer:

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)32)
{
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

Aquí se pregunta atendiendo al **código ASCII** donde **32** corresponde a la barra espaciadora.